# Deleting paypal app will cancel subscriptions?

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions

I've tried to reach paypal suport so many times, with no success, so maybe you guys can help with this.

The problem: I'm working on a project that have a paypal account setted up, with 5 apps registered there. The paypal account is an old account that receives many recurring payments and we don't have a way to know in witch app the payments are comming, so I was asked to solve the problem trying to create just one paypal app but withou losing any subscription.

The question: How can I delete the apps on paypal dashboard and create a new one without lose any payments?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an app will either cancel the subscriptions, or it won't, but either way you won't be accomplishing your goal of "to know in which app the payments are coming", since nothing you do will move existing subscriptions to a new app, other than having the user cancel and subscribe again.

So, for your stated goal of "to know in which app the payments are coming", the best you can do is settle on which single app to use ***going forward***, and always use that app for ***new*** subscriptions. There exists no way to keep old subscriptions active and have them take place in a different app.

And anyway, assuming you leave your apps active, each app can have its own [webhook event listeners.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions)

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. Well, sorry for not being so clear on my question, but the reason they want to "merge the apps into one" is that in some of these apps the webhooks are not working. But I understand that what they want to do is not possible. I'll have to find another way to solve this problem. Thank you so much.